# Negating a statement with nested quantifiers

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

I'm working on the following exercise:

*Prove that a simple graph G with at least four vertices is 3-connected if and only if for every triple (x,y,z) of distinct vertices and any edge e not incident with y, G has an x,z-path through e that does not contain y.*

For the (=>) direction, I'm trying to approach it with a proof by contradiction, but I'm having some trouble negating the following statement:

*For every triple (x,y,z) of distinct vertices and any edge e not incident with y, G has an x,z-path through e that does not contain y.*

I have:

*There exists a triple (x,y,z) of distinct vertices such that for any edge e not incident with y, G does not have an x,z-path through e which does not contain y.*

But that doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is correct - I wrote it down separately, and came to the same statement as you.

However, you can neaten *"G does not have an x,z-path through e which does not contain y."*

to *"All x,z-paths through e belonging to G contains y."* as it is a double negative.

So your final statement would be:

*There exists a triple (x,y,z) of distinct vertices such that for any edge e not incident with y, all x,z-paths through e belonging to G contains y.*

This can be neatened since "any edge e", really means "all edges e"

so:

*Let us assume that there exists a triple (x,y,z) of distinct vertices such that for all edges e not incident with y, all x,z-paths through e belonging to G contains y.*